# How to get the frequency of numbers in a list according to a second consecutive list

Tags: python, frequency

I am new to python

I found topics on about counting frequency of numbers in a list. However, in my problem I want to get the frequency corresponding to a second consecutive list so that missing elements are assigned zero counts.
My searched list:

```
Earthquake_Magnitude = [ 3.5  4.4  3.4  3.6  3.2  3.3  3.7  3.   3.1  4.3  3.9  3.2  3.1  3.2  3.6  3.1  4.   3.5  4.4  3.   3.   3.6  4.2  3.7  3.1  3.4  3.1  3.6  3.4  3.  4.1  3.4  4.2  3.4  3.9  3.   3.9  3.   3.   3.5  3.2  3.1]
```

My second list:

```
Magnitude_bins = [ 3.   3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.   4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import groupby and define your lists with 2.9 added as a proof of the 0 as your predefined results are all in magnitude_bins.

```
from itertools import groupby

# Predefined lists from the question with the addition of 2.9 for proof of 0
earthquake_magnitude = [3.5, 4.4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.2, 3.3, 3.7, 3.0, 3.1, 4.3, 3.9,
                        3.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.6, 3.1, 4.0, 3.5, 4.4, 3.0, 3.0, 3.6,
                        4.2, 3.7, 3.1, 3.4, 3.1, 3.6, 3.4, 3.0, 4.1, 3.4, 4.2,
                        3.4, 3.9, 3.0, 3.9, 3.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.2, 3.1, 2.9]
magnitude_bins = [3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1,
                  4.2, 4.3, 4.4]
```

Now sort the list so that groupby can do its thing

```
earthquake_magnitude.sort()
```

Now we create a list of strings of "magnitude: count" if it is in magnitude_bins otherwise make the count = 0

```
output = [str(key) + ": " + str(len(list(group))) if key in magnitude_bins \
       else str(key) + ": " + str(0) \
       for key, group in groupby(earthquake_magnitude)]
```

Show the output

```
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for all. This works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define your lists:

```
>>> Earthquake_Magnitude = [3.5, 4.4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.2, 3.3, 3.7, 3., 3.1, 4.3, 3.9, 3.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.6, 3.1, 4., 3.5, 4.4, 3., 3., 3.6, 4.2, 3.7, 3.1, 3.4, 3.1, 3.6, 3.4, 3., 4.1, 3.4, 4.2, 3.4, 3.9, 3., 3.9, 3., 3., 3.5, 3.2, 3.1]
>>> Magnitude_bins = [3., 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4., 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4]
```

Now, let's get a count of entries in `Earthquake_Magnitude` ignoring any entry not in `Magnitude_bins`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(x for x in Earthquake_Magnitude if x in set(Magnitude_bins))
>>> c
Counter({3.0: 7, 3.1: 6, 3.4: 5, 3.2: 4, 3.6: 4, 3.9: 3, 3.5: 3, 4.4: 2, 4.2: 2, 3.7: 2, 3.3: 1, 4.1: 1, 4.3: 1, 4.0: 1})
```

As you can see `3.0` occurred 7 times in `Earthquake_Magnitude`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be best off creating a "dictionary", which is a lookup table from keys to values in Python. In this case, your "key" (the thing you put into the dictionary to query it) will be the magnitude of the earthquake, and the "value" (what comes out of the dictionary on a query) will be the number of earthquakes of that magnitude.

So, you can try:

```
from collections import defaultdict

freq = defaultdict(int)

for thisEvent in Earthquake_Magnitude:
    freq[thisEvent] += 1

for thisBin in Magnitude_bins:
    print(str(thisBin) + " has frequency " + str(freq[thisBin]))
```

Where in this case, a `defaultdict` is a dictionary that has a default value, so as to make all of your starting frequencies 0.